# Should I buy APU or CPU keeping in mind I will add a GPU in near future

Tags: graphics-cards, motherboard, pc

Okay so I had finalized ryzen **5600G** APU because I can't afford GPU at the moment. So I'll add a GPU after couple of years when it get cheaper.

So far, I had read that there's not much difference between 'Processing' performance of an APU and equivalent CPU.

For example, the **5600X** CPU. It is same as 5600G but just lacks an integrated GPU.

Now, I just read following things [somewhere](https://linustechtips.com/topic/489115-the-pros-and-cons-of-apus/) - **Pros and Cons of APU**:

```
Pros:

Smaller size - In form factors without enough room for a GPU, an APU is quite discrete.
Size to power - For they're size, they're impressive!
Crossfire capable - GPUs can be added in crossfire for upgradability.

Cons:

Less power - APUs can't pack the same punch as a GPU.
Shared memory - APUs use the same memory for CPU and graphics, limiting the amount.
Limited GPU crossfire options - Not everything works with these.
```

I quite don't understand what he meant by **crossfire**, but in the 3rd cons, he said limited GPU crossfire options. Not everything works with these...

So what *I've* concluded from this con is that 5600X will have more options of compatible GPUs (when I will upgrade) whereas 5600G will have less options available of compatible GPUs. *(This is what I've concluded. I don't know the reasons, if any, for this)*

For example, it could be possible that 5600X supports 10 different GPUs. But 5600G will support only 7 of them.

So is it true for these processors?

I can make my final buying decision based on only this. If there's no compatibility issue, I'll go with 5600G otherwise I'll buy 5600X and a cheap separate GPU.

**So which one should I buy given that I don't want compatibility issues later?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most modern CPUs are "APUs" and I actually recommend getting something with onboard graphics. 5600G is a *better* option here.

> I can't afford GPU at the moment

This is a *great* reason, especially in the great everything shortage to get a CPU with a decent onboard GPU.

I have an older/worse/laptop grade ryzen and... those things don't too bad, and even hold up well with casual gaming. I'd second Irsu's suggestion of getting dual channel ram, and the fastest you can afford

To start with - while setting up, and in future, it gives you a 'known good' graphics output for setup and testing.

"Crossfire" and "SLI" are vaguely obsolete and are ways to "tag team" two *identical* CPUs. The 'replacement' for it is [explicit multi GPU](https://developer.nvidia.com/explicit-multi-gpu-programming-directx-12). This is not a factor here.

The integrated GPU can be disabled if a discrete GPU is in (or kept enabled) - in windows 10 and better, you could, in theory, set some applications to use the integrated GPU specifically for various reasons.In my case, I run additional monitors off my onboard graphics.

There's no downside, or compatibility issues with a integrated GPU other than that "you're potentially paying a little bit more for silicon you arn't using". In this case, it feels like a much better option than buying a "cheap" and probably overpriced GPU you're going to not need when you get your proper GPU.

Comment: Yesterday I came to know that 5600G don't have PCI 4.0 but 5600X has. That shouldn't make much difference when I use a PCI 4.0 GPU in near future?

Comment: IMO not that much. Strangely enough - PCI 4.0 is more 'useful' at present for storage than GPUs. PCIe is generally cross compatible across generations. IMO for most part its not going to be a 'big deal'

Answer (score 2):

Forget crossfire/SLI, thats not in this time anymore. Just get the Ryzen 5600G and a motherboard that has the display outputs needed. Dont use single-channel RAM though, always at least dual channel 3200Mhz with apus.

Comment: Thanks. "that has the display outputs needed" meaning?

Comment: Your motherboard needs like hdmi or displayport. You can look it up in the motherboard specs

Comment: Isn't this already included with latest motherboards which have the whole usb and audio panels attached with it? Basically you meant the port for display monitor right?

Comment: yes, and it is indeed included with most motherboards

Comment: Okay. Are you sure crossfire issue don't exist now and GPU can be added without any problem?

Comment: Forget crossfire please, that barely exists and you can ignore it. A gaming laptop also has two gpus and that runs without issue

Comment: And Journeyman Geek sais its only with identical gpu's, and I agree

Comment: Do you mean identical CPUs?

Comment: Both, but mostly gpus

Comment: Pardon me I'm not getting what you want to say.

Comment: Just get that apu. If you get a gpu, just get a gpu.